# Como remover barra lateral com CSS ou de outra forma?

Tags: html, css

Estou aplicando um exemplo de um livro que estou lendo. só que de fazer a formatação com CSS a página exibe além da barra de rolagem natural uma dentro da classe `div` que criei.

Segue uma imagem de como fica o site depois que ele renderiza.

[image: Barra lateral a mais.]

[Link do Repositório no GitHub com os códigos da página abaixo.](https://github.com/NessaRibeiro/ExAmazeriffic)

Comment: Tire o `overflow:scroll` do elemento `<main>`. Com isto seu layout vai quebrar porque utiliza elementos flutuantes. Para ajustar isto você pode usar [esta solução](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na `div` específica use as propriedades `overflow-y: hidden;` e/ou `overflow-x: hidden;` dependendo de qual barra quer suprimir (pode ser as duas).

Existem algumas extensões em alguns navegadores mas é recomendado não usá-las a não ser que seja realmente necessário. Pode ser necessário se quiser alguma manipulação específica que só a extensão permite ou se uma versão do navegador não possui a forma padrão mostrada acima.

Para atender o que o renan colocou no comentário achei [essa solução no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23771140/221800):

```css
.viewport {
    overflow: auto;
 
    /* Make sure the inner div is not larger than the container
     * so that we have room to scroll.
     */
    max-height: 100%;

    /* Pick an arbitrary margin/padding that should be bigger
     * than the max width of all the scroll bars across
     * the devices you are targeting.
     * padding = -margin
     */
    margin-right: -100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

.hide-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Optional styles */
.hide-scroll {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.hide-scroll:after {
    content: '';
    height: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(rgba(219,219,219,0)), to(rgba(211,211,211,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(219,219,219,0) 0%, rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(219,219,219,0) 0%, rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(219,219,219,0) 0%, rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(219,219,219,0) 0%, rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00dbdbdb', endColorstr='#d3d3d3',GradientType=0 );
}
.viewport p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hidden scrollbar</h1>
<hr>
<div class="hide-scroll">
    <div class="viewport">
        <h2>Explaination</h2>
        <p>This example hides the scroll bar of the inner div by hiding the outer div's overflow, and by applying a negative margin to <i>pull</i> the scrollbar off of the screen. There's an equal padding applied to the inner div to counter the negative margin so that the content does not get pulled out of the viewport.</p>
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/NoScrollBar.js).

Tem até um [**JSFiddle** demonstrando que funciona](http://jsfiddle.net/H47fp/).

Comment: Obrigada! Funcionou...

Comment: @bigown o problema de usar `overflow` é que o usuário fica impossibilitado de rolar a página. Dependendo do caso, se houver mais informações abaixo ele não consegue visualizar.

Comment: @renan concordo mas isto não está especificado na pergunta

Comment: @bigown é, pode ser. De qualquer forma ela aceitou como resposta correta então resolveu o problema.

Comment: Sim, mas ao utilizar overflow-y: hidden; a barra de rolagem do navegador continuou funcionando... A barra ao qual me referia era aquela que aparecia dentro da tag main... quando fiz a alteração, a barra sumiu o problema foi resolvido... Mas muito obrigada pela ajuda...

Comment: @VanessaRibeiro em alguns navegadores vai funcionar em outros não. Em alguns vai funcionar se usar a extensões que eu falei. Ou usar um truque mais geral como eu postei acima.